# Why is this synchronized code code _not_ slow?

Tags: java, azure-functions, synchronization

### The Function

I have the following Azure Function, which displays a race condition:

```java
public class Function {

    final RefWrapper toReturn = new RefWrapper();

    private static class RefWrapper {
        String value = "";
    }

    @FunctionName("raceConditionTest")
    public synchronized HttpResponseMessage raceConditionTest(
        @HttpTrigger(
            name = "req",
            methods = {HttpMethod.GET},
            authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS
        ),
        HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
        final ExecutionContext context
    ) throws IOException {
        toReturn.value = request.getHeaders().getOrDefault("x-return-me", "0");
        Thread.sleep(1000 * 10);
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body(toReturn.value).build();
    }
}
```

When I call this function 10 times in parallel, with a different value in the header, all ten requests return the same value, as is expected - a race condition is achieved. If I synchronise, as seen here:

```java
@FunctionName("raceConditionTest")
public synchronized HttpResponseMessage raceConditionTest( /*args*/ ) {
    synchronized (toReturn) {
        toReturn.value = request.getHeaders().getOrDefault("x-return-me", "0");
        Thread.sleep(1000 * 10);       
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body(toReturn.value).build();
    }
}
```

and send parallel requests, then, as expected, each request returns the input value correctly, the race condition has been prevent.

However, unexpectedly, all requests return at the same time, they don't seem to queue. I've looked at my metrics, and no additional function instances are being created.

### The Question

So why is this code not slow, why do requests not have to wait? I'm assuming this behaviour is related to the Azure Function runtime - is it guaranteed, documented, or reasonably expected to be stable?

Comment: I don't know whether Azure Functions execute simultaneous calls in the same JVM, but given that `raceConditionTest` itself is synchronized, why does adding a synchronized block inside it change the behaviour?

Comment: Good question! `synchronized` in the signature was insufficient to prevent the race condition, in any case. I have not actually tested what happens if I have a non-synchronized method with a synchronized block...